# The Odin Project Stock Picker. Struggling to begin to solve in Ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I am currently doing the stock picker problem on Odin and I am struggling to even begin to tackle the problem. I spent a good while trying to implement my thoughts into code but to no avail...So I looked at another solution for inspiration to see if it could help me try and solve the problem. What is best_sell = j + (i + 1) doing? I cannot figure out how that chooses the highest sell date after the purchase date?
http://www.theodinproject.com/courses/ruby-programming/lessons/building-blocks?ref=lnav

```
def stock_picker(arr)
    best_buy = 0
    best_sell = 0
    max_profit = 0
    arr[0..-2].each_with_index do |buy, i|
        arr[(i+1)..-1].each_with_index do |sell, j|
            if (sell - buy) > max_profit
                best_sell = j + (i + 1)
                best_buy = i
                max_profit = sell - buy
            end
        end
    end
    [best_buy, best_sell]
end

puts stock_picker([17,3,6,9,15,8,6,1,10]).inspect
```

Answer (score 0):

`i` and `j` represent indexes in the array. Does that help you understand what the function returns when it completes? (Does it return values or indexes?)

Hint: how might it help you to keep track of the lowest purchase price seen so far as you traverse the array in constructing a more efficient solution?

Comment: I understand that i and j represend the indexes. But I do not understand why j + (i + 1) finds the highest sell date? Why would it not simply be j? what does the i + 1 offer?

Comment: @nickyheise add a line that logs `j` to the console during the loop with the `j`s. What do you see?